# como sumar iva con clases en javascript

Tags: javascript

es un algoritmo para calcular cuanto te costara cada plan dependiendo de los meses que lo desees contratar, pero quisiera que el precio al final en el `alert` me salga con método `sumarIva()` y que me arroje tanto el precio sin `iva` y luego el precio con `iva`, mi código es el siguiente:

```
class planes{
    constructor(nombrePlan, precio, duracion){
    this.nombrePlan = nombrePlan;
    this.precio = parseFloat(precio); //precio mensual
    this.duracion = parseInt(duracion);
    }
    
    meses(valor){
        if(valor == 3){
            this.precio *= valor;
            return valor
        }else if(valor == 6){
            this.precio *= valor;
            return valor
        }else if(valor == 12){
            this.precio *= valor;
            return valor
        }else{
            return 0
        }
    }
    sumarIva(){
        this.precio *= 1.21
    }
        
    
}

const plan11 = new planes("Plan Integral", 20, 3 )
const plan12 = new planes("Plan Integral", 20, 6 )
const plan13 = new planes("Plan Integral", 20, 12 )
const plan21 = new planes("Plan Intermedio", 15, 3 )
const plan22 = new planes("Plan Intermedio", 15, 6 )
const plan23 = new planes("Plan Intermedio", 15, 12 )
const plan31 = new planes("Plan Economico", 10, 3 )
const plan32 = new planes("Plan Economico", 10, 6 )
const plan33 = new planes("Plan Economico", 10, 12 )

let plan = prompt("Ingrese el plan deseado: ");
let cantidadMeses = prompt("Ingrese la duracion, 3, 6 o 12 meses: ");
if(plan11.meses(cantidadMeses)){

    alert("ud ha elegido: " + plan11.nombrePlan + "Con una duracion de: "
    + plan11.duracion + "con un precio de: " + plan11.precio + 
    "Incluyendo el IVA quedaria asi: " + sumarIva())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que retornar un valor en el metodo `sumarIva()`.  Quedaria asi:

```js
class planes{
    constructor(nombrePlan, precio, duracion){
    this.nombrePlan = nombrePlan;
    this.precio = parseFloat(precio); //precio mensual
    this.duracion = parseInt(duracion);
    }
    
    meses(valor){
        if(valor == 3){
            this.precio *= valor;
            return valor
        }else if(valor == 6){
            this.precio *= valor;
            return valor
        }else if(valor == 12){
            this.precio *= valor;
            return valor
        }else{
            return 0
        }
    }
    sumarIva(){
        return this.precio *= 1.21
    }
        
    
}

const plan11 = new planes("Plan Integral", 20, 3 )
const plan12 = new planes("Plan Integral", 20, 6 )
const plan13 = new planes("Plan Integral", 20, 12 )
const plan21 = new planes("Plan Intermedio", 15, 3 )
const plan22 = new planes("Plan Intermedio", 15, 6 )
const plan23 = new planes("Plan Intermedio", 15, 12 )
const plan31 = new planes("Plan Economico", 10, 3 )
const plan32 = new planes("Plan Economico", 10, 6 )
const plan33 = new planes("Plan Economico", 10, 12 )

let plan = prompt("Ingrese el plan deseado: ");
let cantidadMeses = prompt("Ingrese la duracion, 3, 6 o 12 meses: ");
if(plan11.meses(cantidadMeses)){

    alert("ud ha elegido: " + plan11.nombrePlan + " Con una duracion de: "
    + plan11.duracion + " con un precio de: " + plan11.precio + 
    "Incluyendo el IVA quedaria asi: " + plan11.sumarIva())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que ingresas a la función `sumarIva()` nunca está sucediendo nada, porque no estás retornando nada, solamente bastaría poner el `return` dentro de la función:

```
sumarIva() {
  return this.precio *= 1.21;
}
```

También, estás tratando de ingresar a `sumarIva()` así:

```
..."Incluyendo el IVA quedaria asi: " + sumarIva())
```

De la cual es incorrecto, tu función esta dentro de la clase `planes`, tendrías que ingresar de esta forma:

```
..."Incluyendo el IVA quedaria asi: " + plan11.sumarIva())
```

Código:

```js
class planes {
  constructor(nombrePlan, precio, duracion) {
    this.nombrePlan = nombrePlan;
    this.precio = parseFloat(precio); //precio mensual
    this.duracion = parseInt(duracion);
  }

  meses(valor) {
    if (valor == 3) {
      this.precio *= valor;
      return valor;
    } else if (valor == 6) {
      this.precio *= valor;
      return valor;
    } else if (valor == 12) {
      this.precio *= valor;
      return valor;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  sumarIva() {
    return this.precio *= 1.21;
  }
}

const plan11 = new planes('Plan Integral', 20, 3);
const plan12 = new planes('Plan Integral', 20, 6);
const plan13 = new planes('Plan Integral', 20, 12);
const plan21 = new planes('Plan Intermedio', 15, 3);
const plan22 = new planes('Plan Intermedio', 15, 6);
const plan23 = new planes('Plan Intermedio', 15, 12);
const plan31 = new planes('Plan Economico', 10, 3);
const plan32 = new planes('Plan Economico', 10, 6);
const plan33 = new planes('Plan Economico', 10, 12);

let plan = prompt('Ingrese el plan deseado: ');
let cantidadMeses = prompt('Ingrese la duracion, 3, 6 o 12 meses: ');
if (plan11.meses(cantidadMeses)) {
  alert("ud ha elegido: " + plan11.nombrePlan + " Con una duracion de: "
    + plan11.duracion + " con un precio de: " + plan11.precio + 
    " Incluyendo el IVA quedaria asi: " + plan11.sumarIva())
}
```